# Вставить значение в массив, если они совпадают по ключам

Tags: php, массивы

Есть такой массив:

```
//$array_phrase 
Array
(
[112340] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 112340
                [1] => 4448741
                [2] => Отдых
                [3] => -
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 112340
                [1] => 4448743
                [2] => Работа
                [3] => +
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 112340
                [1] => 4448742
                [2] => Объявления
                [3] => +
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 112340
                [1] => 4448740
                [2] => Лето
                [3] => -
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => 112340
                [1] => 4448739
                [2] => Погода
                [3] => -
            )
    )
```

И такой:

```
//$temp
Array
(
    [112340] => Array
        (
            [0] => 70557
            [1] => 70558
            [2] => 70559
        )

)
Array
(
    [112367] => Array
        (
            [0] => 70648
            [1] => 70649
            [2] => 70650
        )

)
Array
(
    [112372] => Array
        (
            [0] => 70661
            [1] => 70662
            [2] => 70663
        )

)
Array
(
    [112419] => Array
        (
            [0] => 70735
        )

)
Array
(
    [112477] => Array
        (
            [0] => 70868
            [1] => 70869
            [2] => 70867
            [3] => 70865
            [4] => 70866
        )

)
```

Как сделать добавление в первый массив новый вложенный массив (после [3]), если они по ключам будут одинаковы, то для каждой записи первого массива - добавляем значение второго массива типо того:

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 112340
                [1] => 4448741
                [2] => Отдых
                [3] => -
                [4] => array (
                               [0] => 70557
                               [1] => 70558
                               [2] => 70559)
            )
```

Только для каждого элемента первого массива.
PHP Code:

```
$container_phrase = array();
    foreach($id_temp as $one_id_temp)
    {
        $identifier_project = $one_id_temp;
        $url_phrases  = "https://site.com/api/project/$identifier_project/phrases"; 
        $get_all_phrases = connectToSite($url_phrases, $token);
        foreach($get_all_phrases as $value_phrase)
        {
            $phrase = $value_phrase['phrase'];
            if($phrase == null){
                $phrase = 'Данные отсутствуют'; 
            }
            $personal_id = $value_phrase['id'];
            if($personal_id == null){
                $personal_id = '-//-'; 
            }
            $geo = $value_phrase['is_geo']; 
            if($geo == false){
                 //интерпретируем
                $geo = '-';
            }elseif($geo == true){
                $geo = '+';
            } 
            $array_phrase[$identifier_project][] = [$identifier_project, $personal_id, $phrase, $geo];
        }
        $temp = [];
        $url_engines = "https://site.com/api/project/$identifier_project/engines"; 
        $get_all_engines = connectToSite($url_engines, $token);
        foreach($get_all_engines as $arr){
            $temp[$identifier_project][] = $arr['id'];
        }
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($temp); echo "</pre>";
    }
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($array_phrase); echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$primaryArray = [...];
$secondaryArray = [...];

foreach($secondaryArray as $key => $value){
    if(isset($primaryArray[$key]){
         foreach(array_keys($primaryArray[$key])) as $key2){
              $primaryArray[$key][$key2][] = $value;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Идеально! только на 4 строке ")" забыли, ну это пустяк, а можно uasort использовать для новых значений, от убывания до возрастания значений